# cordova Social Sharing cancel clicked through native share sheet?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

Using cordova native share sheet like this:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaSocialSharing) {
  $scope.share = function() {
    $cordovaSocialSharing
    .share(message, subject, file, link) // Share via native share sheet
    .then(function(result) {
      // Success!
    }, function(err) {
      // An error occured. Show a message to the user
    });
  }
});
```

from html template, using the ng-click directive to invoke the function.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-click="share()"></div>
</div>
```

How could I know whether the user has clicked the cancel button from the share sheet?

I've tried looking at result, but it's always set to true.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: nope, never got to solve it.